# How to copy files from node_modules with Vite / SvelteKit?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I have a node module dependency for theming content at `node_modules/foo-styles`.

For most css that I want to pull in, I can simply use an `import 'foo-styles/dist/controls/button.css'` in the page/component and vite does its magic, shoving the css where it fits best.

For theming however, I need to switch the included css variables file based on active theme in my `<svelte:head>` , e.g. reference `foo-styles/dist/themes/{$theme}/color-variables.css` in the markup.
To do so, I assume that vite must copy those files from `node_modules/foo-styles` to my apps asset directory without import magic, renaming of files etc.

I can only find examples for doing this with webpack or rollup using copy plugins ... is this something that vite can do out of the box? Is there a plugin available? How do you copy assets from node_module dependencies to the bundle?

Comment: Can you switch the whole file e.g. in the style of light theme and dark theme? Then it should be as easy as dynamically write `<style>` tag in `<head>` and make sure the relevant CSS files are in the static assets folder. Not sure if any plugin is needed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the approach I am taking. The challenging bit is making sure that "the relevant CSS files are in the static assets folder", since these files reside in node_modules. I have pretty much solved it now (thanks to a maintainer who helped out on their discord) and will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make Vite copy assets and return a URL by adding `?url` to the import. With this you then can just dynamically add a `link` to the `<head>` with said URL.

E.g.

```js
import themeUrl from 'some-module/css/theme.css?url'

onMount(() => {
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = themeUrl;
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    return () => link.remove();
});
```

If you do not want to manually list all theme imports, you can use Vite's [glob import feature](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import). Here the URL has to be written differently as it must start with `/` or `./`:

```js
const styles = import.meta.glob(
    '/node_modules/some-module/css/*.css',
    { query: 'url', eager: true },
);

let selectValue = 'some-theme';
$: selectedStyle = `/node_modules/some-module/css/${selectedValue}.css`;
let link = null;

onMount(() => {
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    return () => link?.remove();
});

$: if (link) {
    const { default: href } = styles[selectedStyle];
    link.href = href;
}
```

You can also use `svelte:head`, which can be simpler and will add the style reference during SSR, however the order of the stylesheets can be inconsistent as the style may be added before other styles on first load but added after these styles on navigation, so rules may be accidentally overridden.

```html
<script>
    const styles = import.meta.glob(
        '/node_modules/some-module/css/*.css',
        { query: 'url', eager: true },
    );
    
    let selectValue = 'some-theme';
    $: href = styles[`/node_modules/some-module/css/${selectedValue}.css`].default;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" {href} />
</svelte:head>
```